# Node Telegram Bot API return Bad Request: there is no photo in the request

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I was wrote a Telegram bot with Nodejs. To send an image to the user I am using the following commands :

```
bot.sendPhoto({
            chat_id: msg.chat.id,
            caption: 'Test caption',
            files: {
                photo: '../change-db-shop-url.png'
            }
        }, function (err, msg) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

This error displayed :

> Unhandled rejection Error: 400
>   {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no
>   photo in the request"}

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved :

```
var photo = __dirname+'/../Android.png';
bot.sendPhoto(msg.chat.id, photo, {caption: "I'm a bot!"});
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
bot.sendPhoto({
  chatId: msg.chat.id,
  caption: 'Test caption',
  photo: '../change-db-shop-url.png'
}, function(err, msg) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(msg);
});
```

https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api#TelegramBot+sendPhoto

Comment: Thanks you, But the problem not resolve! 
‍‍‍‍‍`Unhandled rejection Error: 400 {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no photo in the request"}
`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the photo's url is wrong, Try with another url e.g. : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png

Comment: And with normal messages does it works?
If you don't know how to deploy your bot online take a look here: https://github.com/ilbonte/node-telegram-bot-starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send files from urls:

https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/api.md#file